# Sencha Cmd 5: app build bundle is missing Ext.application function

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I am using Sencha Command 5.1.3.61 (though i've tried other 5.1 versions).  when i run sencha app build testing, the resulting app.js bundle is missing required code from Ext - specifically Ext.application is not defined.

I created an empty project to compare and that one generates app.js just fine, but with my project it is missing a large chunk of what is included in ext-all-rtl-debug.js

following are the key sections from my app.json:

```
"js": [
    {
        "path": "${ext.dir}/build/ext-all-rtl-debug.js"
    },
    {
        "path": "app.js",
        "bundle": true
    },
    {
        "path": "direct/api-debug.js",
        "remote": true
    }
],
"output": {
  "base": "${workspace.build.dir}/${build.environment}/${app.name}",

  "page": {
    "path": "../../../index.html",
    "enable": false
  },
  "microloader": {
    "path": "microloader.js",
    "embed": true,
    "enable": true
  }

},
```

Comment: Do you see any missing classes while testing (without building the app)?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. sencha app upgrade -ext[version] left some 4.x files layout around which broke the bundle.  i replaced the ext folder with a clean 5.1 tree and it is now working